# facebook ads insights - adding day dimension breakdown

Tags: facebook-ads-api

We are using the 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/ endpoint to get insights for a Facebook ad-account.

To get data for a few days with a day breakdown (for analytical purposes) we are creating a report per day and by doing so increasing our calls and reaching limits.

Is it possible to create a single report with a day breakdown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is parameter `time_increment`, as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/).

To get insights broken down to single days, use `time_increment=1`

Comment: time_increment doesn't fetch all data.. For example I am going to fetch day wise day for last 1 year, `time_increment` will fetch only ` month data day wise.